# Django logout url with GET values

Tags: django, url, logout

I have url config based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout

Here it is:

```
url(r'^logout(?P<next_page>.*)$', 'logout', name='auth_logout_next'),
```

In template I use such code:

```
<a href="{% url auth_logout_next request.path %}">{% trans "Logout" %}</a>
```

It works nice, yet I have possible GET value in some pages - `?page=2`, so request.path drops those values. How should I pass not only the existing page but also GET values if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url auth_logout_next request.get_full_path|urlencode %}">{% trans "Logout" %}</a>
```